# My website has white background and texts, how to fix it?

Tags: dreamweaver

When I joined the Hostinger hosting site, all my problems messed up. My website won't go live for no reason. When I go to the site, it has white background. No full design just white background and texts. (visit my website 'www.saintscommunity.org')

So the Hostinger support told me, "Looks like the URL's or something else in the code may be messing up here. From the errors in the page I can see that your files are not being loaded: [image]"

Is there way I can fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Any code you can share with us?

Answer (score 0):

For the website, I've seen a list of errors in my chrome dev console. I have not read them all but most of them are `404` errors.

Looks like you are using some css files. If you intend to use them, be sure to place them in the correct directory in your server.
If you have already placed them in your server correctly, I think it might has something to do with permissions.

Answer (score 0):

for example this is the logo  tag in your code :

```
<img src="event details/images/web church logo/logo.png" alt="church logo" class="img-responsive">
```

the "src" attribute of all tags such as image, CSS and script start with "event details" 
    you should remove it from your code then publish and deploy your website.

i change the code of your web site and capture it from my screen and i think it should be like this pic :
[image]